# Delete sent mails that do not have a label

Tags: gmail

I would like to erase the sent messages, but many of them have a label since they are in a folder, and these I do not need to erase.
How can I delete the sent mails that do not have label?

Answer (score 2):

Search for

```
in:sent has:nouserlabels
```

Then "select all", then click the link to really choose *all* messages, then delete.